# Java, FileReader() only seems to be reading the first line of text document?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader

I'm still in the process of learning so please correct me if I'm misunderstanding, but shouldn't the FileReader object return the entire contents of a text file?

I have a snippet of code here where I'm simple trying to take the contents of a short .txt file, and print it using system.out.println()

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    File testDoc = new File("C:\\Users\\Te\\Documents\\TestDocument.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(testDoc));
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader(testDoc));


    try {
      System.out.println(reader.readLine());
    } finally {
      reader.close();
    }
  }
}
```

The .txt file contains only 3 lines, formatted like so:

```
some text here, more text and stuff
new estonian lessons
word = new word
```

However the program is only printing the first line in the file.

```
some text here, more text and stuff
```

What is causing this, and how do I correct it?

I've tried reading the documentation, as well as searching through Stackoverflow, but I haven't been able to find the solution to this problem.

Comment: don't you miss some kind of loop? (Note that there are more *modern* way to read a text file)

Comment: `readLine()` does just that, reads only 1 line - it does not mean `readFile()`. You say you read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) but I find that hard to believe because the first line of the documentation states "Reads a line of text" and then goes on to define what a line of text is.

Comment: That's because you're only calling `readLine` once. Why would you expect the whole file being read?

Comment: @shawn FileReader will not read entire contents of file. Think of it practically, if there is a huge file and FileReader reads entire file then we will start having memory issues.

Comment: @RC. what would you recommend? My knowledge is limited, I'm just using readLine() as I came across it in a demo on exceptions and error handling

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path- is an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`BufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html)'s (look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine())) `readLine()` reads a single line from the file, so you need to write a loop as shown below:

```
String line = "";
 while((line =reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
 }
```

Also, you don't need `Scanner` object in your code (if you use `BufferedReader`), so it would be simply as shown below:

```
        File testDoc = new File("C:\\Users\\Te\\Documents\\TestDocument.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(testDoc));
        try {
             String line = "";
             while((line =reader.readLine()) != null) {
                 System.out.println(line);
             }
        } finally {
          reader.close();
        }
```

Comment: So does readLine() automatically move on to the next line with each reiteration of the loop? (also the scanner was there for another reason, I just forgot to delete it.)

Comment: yes, you are right, it will move as part of `while`

Comment: Seems to have done the trick, and lots of useful info here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may use the Scanner that is actually instantiated but not used to chain it with a `FileReader` instance.
 It could allow to have the flexible api  of `Scanner` class that has `hasNextLine()` and `nextLine()` methods.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader(testDoc));


public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    File testDoc = new File("C:\\TestDocument.txt");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader(testDoc));

    try {
        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            String currentLine = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println(currentLine);
        }
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `readLine()` just returns one line. So you have to iterate over all lines:

```
while(reader.hasNextLine()){
    String currentLine = reader.readLine();
}
```

Comment: `BufferedReader` has not `hasNextLine()` method. `Scanner` has.

Comment: @davidxxx I was just about to make a comment on this, but yes I get a reference error when trying to call .hasNextLine()

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do it. See below.

```
 File testDoc = new File("C:\\Users\\Te\\Documents\\TestDocument.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(testDoc));
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader(testDoc));
    try {

      //Using Scanner Object
      while(in.hasNextLine()){
          System.out.println(in.nextLine());
      }

    //Using BufferReader Object
      String line=reader.readLine();
      while(line!=null){
          System.out.println(line);
          line=reader.readLine();
      }

    } finally {
      reader.close();
    }
```