# While loop doesn't break after reading multiple line of text with BufferedReader in Java Socket

Tags: java, sockets, while-loop, bufferedreader, java-io

I have trying to send multiple lines of code from a client to the server.

Here is the code on the server side

```
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);

            //read client input
            //multi line 
            //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43416889/java-filereader-only-seems-to-be-reading-the-first-line-of-text-document?newreg=2f77b35c458846dbb1290afce8853930
            String line = "";
            while((line =in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            System.out.println("is it here?");
```

Here is the code on the client side :

```
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    BufferedReader keyboard = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);

    while (true) {
        System.out.print("> ");

        //content server input command (put, lamport clock, message)
        String command = keyboard.readLine();
        if (command.equals("quit")){
            break;
        }
        //read from CSDB/txt1.txt
        String message = readFileReturnString("CSDB/txt1.txt", StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        System.out.println(message);
        //send to clientHandler through PrintWriter
        out.println(command + " 3 \n" + message);

        //receive response from ClientHandler (lamport clock)
        String serverResponse = input.readLine();
        System.out.println(serverResponse + socket);
    }
```

Server side is able to print out all the text that is sent from the client side. However, the while loop doesn't break and System.out.println("is it here?"); has never been executed.

May I know why and how I can solve this problem please?

Comment: You need to close the socket.

Comment: But I would like to reuse this socket. As I may send the message from client to server more than once.

Comment: Then you need to tell server when it should exit the loop. Yo may send special string or something.

Comment: Or use non-blocking

Comment: @g00se it won't help.

Comment: @talex not sure why you say that

Comment: @g00se because non-blocking IO wont help server to understand when this specific part of communication is over. If you think I'm wrong can you please explain your suggestion in more details.

Comment: @talex Well, I read *Is it here?* as "this is a debugging line" rather than "I haven't got a clue about what the client is going to send". So, if my guess is correct, when a 'unit of communication' has arrived in non-blocking IO, that unit can be captured and processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ talex
Then you need to tell server when it should exit the loop. Yo may send special string or something.

This works fine.

```
        String line = "";
        while((line =in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            if (line.equals("break") {
            break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Client is waiting for some response of the Server. But the Server does not send any response. The Server writes to the `System.out` only. The Server has to write the response with the `out`.

```
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);

        //read client input
        //multi line 
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43416889/java-filereader-only-seems-to-be-reading-the-first-line-of-text-document?newreg=2f77b35c458846dbb1290afce8853930
        String line = "";
        while((line =in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            out.println(line);  // send Server response
        }
        System.out.println("is it here?");
```